# Editable text from a Photoshop or Fireworks design

Tags: html, text, dreamweaver, photoshop, fireworks

I want to redesign my site using Photoshop as the graphic design application, Fireworks as the slicing/rollover application (even though Photoshop can slice, I know), and Dreamweaver as everything else between design and publishing.
I put filler text (Lorem Ipsum) in my PS designs, and some of the homepage's text zones are on gradients and other non-monochromatic photos. When I export from Photoshop, I can export slices as HTML, but obviously, deleting the slice would clear both the text and the gradient underneath (and anything else in its path). 
I'll get right to the point: is there any way to export from FW or PS so as to later be able to edit text zones in Dreamweaver? It would make content management so much easier to know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Hide the text in Photoshop before you export that slice, then in Dreamweaver set that slice as the background of something like a `<div>` or `<td>` with css `background-image:url(...);` and add your text on top of that in Dreamweaver.

Questions like this that don't involve programming are more appropriate for superuser.com - you should ask similar questions there in the future when they don't involve any code but just how to use software.

Comment: Alright that works. Sorry if this isn't the right forum for this type of question — I just saw a lot of web design questions in one place.